# Mysql create index boolen or varchar for better performance and storage

Tags: mysql

I have a query

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id=1 && image!=""...
```

in my index

```
post_id, image
```

table

```
post_id, text, image
```

my question is

Is this good idea to put image into index, (image will be varchar, 1320-26541-335.jpg)

or should I create another `column(tinyint)` and set boolen to identify user have upload image or not, basically  I just need to find out user have upload image or not

(if user didn't upload image, they field will be " " empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a prefix index of 1 character, which would be the same size of an index on a tinyint, and you won't have to add a new column or worry if its value is out of sync with the `image` string.

```
ALTER TABLE posts ADD KEY (post_id, image(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image field as `varchar` and save the path of the uploaded image (or just the name of the image) in it. let it be null if no image is uploaded!

This way I do not think you need to set it `index` since it is rarely used to search for images by its name.